# how can i create this array from this starting array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

Hi there i have this starting array:

```
names = [ '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E'];
```

which I need for later on in my application to see who's turn it is. I need to be able to store some values in a different kind of array  like so:

```
scores = [
  {
    id: "1A",
    endScores: {}
  },
  {
    id: "1B",
    endScores: {}
  },
  {
    id: "1C",
    endScores: {}
  },
  {
    id: "1D",
    endScores: {}
  },
  {
    id: "1E",
    endScores: {}
  }
];
```

How is it possible to get from my first array to the second array? The first array can also change in its size there can be more or less names in there... Hope there is a possible way. PS: I'm using Angular 2.

Comment: Have a look at [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @AlekseyL.could u pls be a bit more specific as im new to javascript and these arrays are blowing my mind appart :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can map your `names` array into desired collection.

```js
const names = [ '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E'];

const transformToScores = names => names.map(id => ({id, endScores: {}}))

const scores = transformToScores(names)

console.log(scores)
```

Comment: will this then edit names? or will names stay like the original form?

Comment: @ArcherMark what do you mean? names are mapped to `id` property in the second collection without any transformation.

Comment: will the array of names stay in the format it was original or will that array be changed? i see that with youre code u are also creating a new array called scores. _transformToScores = names => _ this line is what is confusing me where my brain is saying that the names array is getting changed. But since i am new i could be completely wrong ...

Comment: @ArcherMark no, it stays the same. There's no mutability here. `map` method always returns new array.

Comment: @ArcherMark if this answers your question please mark this answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `map` method it's pretty easy:

```js
const names = [ '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E'];

const scores = names.map(name => {
  let item = {
    id: name,
    endScores: {}
  }
  return item;
})

console.log(scores);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names = [ '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E'];

const newnames=names.map(Id=>Object.assign({},{
    id: Id,
    endScores: {}
    }
    ))
console.log(newnames)
```